# How to get all the bugs associated with a particular project

Tags: launchpad, launchpadlib, launchpad-api

I am looking a way to get all the bugs assocaited with particular project using launchpad API.
I wanted to use some kind of clustering alogrithm to divide the bugs into predefined catagories.

Comment: I think the stack overflow site is better for this kind of question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is a bit late but the following worked for me (in case anyone else is looking for the same thing):

```python
launchpad = Launchpad.login_anonymously('lplib.cookbook.json_fetcher', 'production', cachedir, version = 'devel')

project = launchpad.projects['ubuntu'] #where 'ubuntu' is the project name
bugs = project.searchTasks(status = ['New', 'Incomplete', 'Triaged', 'Opinion', 'Invalid', 'Won\'t Fix', 'Confirmed', 'In Progress', 'Fix Committed', 'Fix Released'])

for bug in bugs:
        browser = launchpad._browser
        bugInfo = browser.get(bug.self_link) #gets you the bug information
```

note: you have to import launchpad from launchpad-lib.